# Where do my Snip & Sketch screenshots go after pressing the keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, file-location, snip-and-sketch

In Windows 10 Enterprise x64, I'm trying to use the keyboard shortcut for the Snip & Sketch tool that generates screen captures of my current view. I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and the interface comes up that allows me to screen capture part or all of the screen.

However, when I finish the screenshot, I cannot find where the result is. I do not see any image files get saved, nor is the screenshot copied to my clipboard, nor is there a further interface that opens up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The screenshot goes in the Pictures folder. Open the Snip and Sketch dialogue window that pops up and you can confirm and/or resave if you wish to.

Comment: In my case, when I exit Snip & Sketch it remembers the last folder that I chose to store the image in.

Comment: Note that in order to enter Snip & Sketch I need to open the Action Center and click on the image. Otherwise, it just stays in the clipboard.

Comment: John: it does not appear true that the screenshot goes in the Pictures folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Notifications & actions` settings you can turn notifications on for Snip & Sketch if you haven't, then you'll be able to click on the notification to open it in the tool.

In the tool itself you can go to meatballs menu (`...`) -> `Settings` and configure to both store the screenshots in the clipboard or ask to save as a file once you quit the app.

By default, without asking where to store, it only saves it for me in a seemingly temporary file:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip\{B3D1265A-2485-4421-A749-D0176C2B263F}.png
```

And also some cache file:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\ActionCenterCache\microsoft-screensketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe-app_43064_0.png
```

Also note that you can easily track where new files appear by using e.g. [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) app with `Date modified` descending sorting and perhaps some filters, in this case the default Images one could work, on top.

Comment: Helpful! It turns out my notificatiosn for Snip & Sketch were somehow turned off. Turning them back on made it work again.

Comment: Confirmed:
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip`
contains the latest screenshot(s).
(For me, unfortunately, the one I was searching for was no longer there.)